# android get current playing audio stream type

Tags: android, audio, stream

I want to develop a app which can get current playing audio stream type. and add special audio effect on it according to the stream type,is there any way to get the playing audio stream type? Thanks

Comment: what is a `stream type`?

Comment: Please provide some code to make it clear what are you talking about

Comment: @venjee, did you find a solution for this?